# How to get data-id of only the particular element having particular class and insert it into database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
  <a data-original-title='Facebook' data-id='Facebook' data-placement='top' class='btn tooltip-button soclwrap vertical-button mrg10A pad10B pad10T bg-Facebook **myselected**'><i class='glyph-icon  font-size-35 icon-Facebook'>

 </a><a data-original-title='Twitter' data-id='Twitter' data-placement='top' class='btn tooltip-button soclwrap vertical-button mrg10A pad10B pad10T bg-Twitter'><i class='glyph-icon  font-size-35 icon-Twitter'>
```

I have two icons.When i click it will give a class selected.Here i used facebook and twitter from datbase.so here i clicked facebook so it got a class selected.now when i submit i want to update the data-id of facebook to the database since its have class myselected.is there anyway to achieve this?? for sample i just illustrated two values my databse contain more than 10 values so if i click 5 among 10 that 5 icon data-id should be inserted into the datbase.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `input` element which will be synchronized with the selected icons to hold the value of your selected options. In your case, here is an example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected_opt[]" value="facebook" />
<input type="hidden" name="selected_opt[]" value="twitter" />
```

When you click the icon, add/remove the corresponding `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use jQuery for your issue.

like include the jquery.min.js and write the following code

```
$(".soclwrap").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

here you will get the Data id of which ever Icon you need.